# How to stop emacs resizing its initial frame?

Tags: xorg, emacs, x11-forwarding

This is an annoying problem I've been having for a couple years. I have ubuntu 16.04 installed on an intel PC, and also 18.04 installed on a Windows box under WSL 1. In both cases I am connecting to the ubuntu system with SSH (PuTTY, actually) tunnelling X11, and using Xming as the X server. I used apt-get to install the emacs25 distribution. It works fine except for one annoying problem. When I run emacs, using, for instance

```
emacs ex1.c &
```

I can see that the window initially pops up with some reasonable size, but then immediately resizes itself so that it only shows 3 lines of text. I can resize it manually (i.e., with the mouse), and after that it behaves reasonably. I get essentially the same result with

```
emacs -geometry 80x51 ex1.c &
```

The initial window is now 80x51, but as before, it immediately resizes itself to a squat 80x3 window. I have no ~/.emacs, and no .Xresources. The behavior is identical if I use `emacs -q` or `emacs -Q`.

Why is the emacs frame resizing itself? How do I stop it from doing that?

Comment: Can confirm this happens with MobaXterm as well - whether using its built-in X server or Xming on the local side. Curious.

Comment: I know you say you don't have a .emacs file, but could you please confirm this still happens when you invoke "emacs -q" and "emacs -Q" just to completely rule out some option / config / site init file being responsible?

Comment: @nickcrabtree: Yup, exactly the same behavior with both -q and -Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the same behaviour on CentOS 8.1 with Emacs 26.1.
I ended up adding the following lines to my `~/.emacs` to workaround the issue.
Some values (like 36) caused emacs to still resize down to 3 lines.

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda () (set-frame-height (selected-frame) 37 )))
```

Comment: That works! Thanks.

Comment: Is there any theory why this happens? I'm thinking it would be better to fix it at the root...

Comment: And BTW I see this with VcXsrv 1.18.30.0 also.

Comment: ... and VcXsrv 1.20.8.1 as well as with Xming.